# Make a former question a duplicate of a later one

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I saw [How to get midpoint of polyline in java arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187421/how-to-get-midpoint-of-polyline-in-java-arcobjects)
 that was fast made a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187415/how-to-get-midpoint-of-polyline-using-java-arcobjects

I assume the question has been asked by the same user with different accounts, but this has nothing to do with the topic of my question. As the linked (from now let's call it the **original**) question has worse content and thus is unlikely to be solved (it is even marked as too broad) I´d rather make it a duplicate of the first question which (after my edit) is easier to understand and therefore more likely to be answered in any way.

I also read [this meta-post](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3479/20297) stating that more important than the actual *age* of a post is its *content* to make it a duplicate-original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a few occasions I have made earlier poor questions into duplicates of later much better ones by a different user.  I may even have done that for the same user using a single account over the course of a few hours/days.

On this occasion the two questions were asked by what I believe to be the same person using two different accounts about 10 minutes apart, and appeared to be done to circumvent the first one being placed On Hold.  Both accounts have been asked to take the Tour to learn about how the site works, and still neither has.  Instructions for how to merge accounts have also been provided.

I will be happy to reverse the direction of the duplicates, once the user has merged their accounts and taken the Tour.  If others vote to reverse it sooner then that is fine too.