# Marking a question as a duplicate of another one that doesn't have an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently tried to help a user to solve an issue by adding a comment with a link to another answer that I wrote a couple of days ago.

This is the question where I wrote the comment (*Question A*):

[Certain Color for Value Range](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241258/certain-color-for-value-range)

and the following is the question I linked for solving the issue (*Question B*):

[Classifying slope (flat, slope, steep, very steep) in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238889/classifying-slope-flat-slope-steep-very-steep-in-qgis)

They are both about the classification of rasters and could be solved with an analogous procedure. While the OP of the *Question A* confirmed that the provided link offered a solution, the asker of the *Question B* didn't accept it (but I'm quite sure that my answer offered a valid solution).

In the past, I voted to mark one of the two questions as a duplicate of the other one but, in this case, it is not possible since there isn't an accepted answer on *Question B*.

Which should be the ***suggested behavior*** in this situation? Leaving the comment with the provided link without any further action, writing a similar answer on the new question (i.e. on *Question A*, this is what I have done), waiting for the approval of one of the two questions and marking the other one as a duplicate, or what else?

I found this similar question on GIS Meta:

[Should we close Questions as duplicates of old, unanswered Questions?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3042/should-we-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-old-unanswered-questions)

but it didn't help me to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can mark questions as duplicates of Q&As with unaccepted answers.  In this situation I would recommend flagging (which you did) for a moderator to mark one as a duplicate of the other.

I think this should probably be done instead of adding an answer to the newer question.  Even without it being accepted, you can still get votes on the original, so the new asker can vote for your original answer.  This keeps us a bit cleaner, in having a single Q&A and reducing duplication.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will try to follow the recommended behavior for the next time. If you think that I need to delete one of the two answers, I will do it.

Comment: However, your answer is enough for me: I will wait some time for (eventually) receiving other feedbacks, otherwise I will accept it.

Comment: @mgri Agreed, this is my opinion, so another user and/or moderator may have a different view.  Note that I have marked the *older* question as a duplicate of the *newer* question.  This is because the newer one I think is (marginally) clearer, and also because it has more than one answer provided.  Will see what others have to say.

Comment: We moderators can also mark questions as duplicates even if a question has no answer at all.

Comment: @Midavalo, the answer for the _Question A_ has been accepted in the meanwhile. However, it seems that the recommended behavior would be marking one answer as a duplicate of the other, instead of writing a new answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From my reading of Meta SE posts like [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928/215590) it seems that you should be able to vote to close as a duplicate as long as it has at least one upvoted (and not necessarily accepted) answer.

Personally, I think anyone with the vote to close privilege should be able to nominate a possible duplicate irrespective of whether it has any answers.  Consequently, I have upvoted the question linked in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (in the meanwhile, the answer for the *Question A* has been accepted).

Comment: @mgri By "the answer for Question A" I assume you mean https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4591 - its always best to refer to answers using links because answer 1, answer A, etc suggests the first answer when that can change.

Comment: Sorry, I maintained the same terminology used in my question here; so, _Question A_ is for me [Certain Color for Value Range](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241258/certain-color-for-value-range) and I was referring to it in my previous comment.